# Unable to communicate with LinkObject when importing PDF

Tags: bugs, import, warning-messages, pdf-format

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 11.1**

---

When I try to download some files from the web, I sometimes get an error like this:

```
links = {"http://dip21.bundestag.de/dip21/btd/18/076/1807620.pdf",
         "http://epaper.das-parlament.de/epaper/ausgabe.pdf", 
         "http://gemeindebund.at/images/uploads/downloads/2014/Publikationen/RFGs/2010/RFG_4-2010_-_E-Government_in_Gemeinden_(PDF__2_4MB).pdf", 
         "http://smart-government.eu/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/PB_IRML-SmartSchool.pdf",
         "http://subs.emis.de/LNI/Proceedings/Proceedings261/113.pdf", 
         "http://subs.emis.de/LNI/Proceedings/Proceedings261/163.pdf", 
         "http://subs.emis.de/LNI/Proceedings/Proceedings261/51.pdf", 
         "http://subs.emis.de/LNI/Proceedings/Proceedings261/P-261.pdf", 
         "https://www.bundes-sgk.de/system/files/documents/impulse2_nov2015_final.pdf",
         "https://www.demo-online.de/system/files/demo_05_06_ansicht_pdf_klein.pdf", 
         "https://www.gruene-bw.de/app/uploads/2016/05/GrueneBW-Koalitionsvertrag-2016-Entwurf.pdf", 
         "https://www.itdz-berlin.de/dokumente/splitter/splitter_2005_1.pdf",
         "https://www.normenkontrollrat.bund.de/Webs/NKR/Content/DE/Publikationen/Jahresberichte/2014-10-01_nkr_jahresbericht_2014.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=1", 
         "http://www.beamten-informationen.de/media/pdf/Beamten_Magazin_2008_04.pdf",
         "http://www.dgb.de/themen/++co++541b3e54-263c-11e5-9b43-52540023ef1a",
         "http://www.staedtetag-nrw.de/imperia/md/content/stnrw/internet/2_fachinformationen/2008/ag_4_geoportale_formatiert_korr_kes.pdf", 
         "http://www.vitako.de/Themen%20Dokumente/Vitako_aktuell_01-16.pdf"};
res = Import[#, "Plaintext"] & /@ links

LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.0\SystemFiles\Converters\Binaries\Windows-x86-64\PDF.exe",2011,5].
```

What does this error mean and how can I cleanly handle it (without keeping a PDF.exe in memory)?

Comment: Mathematica invokes a separate process to handle the PDF. The error means that this process crashes. I can reproduce the problem in 11.1.0 on OS X. This looks like a bug. Please report it to [Wolfram Support](http://support.wolfram.com/contact).

Comment: Reproduced with versions 8.0.4, 10.4.1 and 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It works for me with version 9.0.1 on OS X.  But no crash does not mean no bug. It sometimes depends on luck.

Comment: I will report it to Wolfram Support. In the meantime, I need to make the code robust for script mode. Would it be a workaround to restart math.exe every time this error occurs? Can I kill abandoned PDF.exe somehow? Is there some easier way?

Comment: Is there a way to detect if an URL points to a PDF before an Import? One option would be to simply ignore all PDF file until this bug is fixed.

Comment: Well, Plaintext is not an import format.  It is an import element which can be used with PDF (and maybe other formats). Once you downloaded a file, you can use `FileFormat` to figure out what format `Import` would use (is it PDF?).  As a workaround, I would use the `pdftotext` utility, which comes with xpdf or poppler (free and cross platform). It will convert PDFs to plain text, which you can then import with Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for reference, this is my workaround:

```
importPatched[url_, elements_String] := importPatched[url, {elements}];
importPatched[url_List, elements_List] := Dataset[importPatched[#, elements] & /@ url];
importPatched[url_String, elements_List] := Module[{fn, pdftohtml, dlResult, pdfQ, s, elems, result, evData, i},
    pdftohtml = "pdftohtml.exe"; (* edit path if necessary *)
    fn = CreateFile[];
    result = Prepend[Association[Rule[#, Missing[]] & /@ elements], Rule["Link", url]];

    (* download *)
    evData = EvaluationData[URLDownload[url, fn, {"StatusCode", "ContentType"}]];
    If[Not[evData["Success"]], Return[Association[Prepend["Status" -> "URLDownload Error " <> StringRiffle[ToString /@ evData["Messages"], ", "], result]]]];
    dlResult = evData["Result"];
    If[dlResult["StatusCode"] =!= 200,
        Quiet[DeleteFile[fn]];
        Return[Prepend[result, "Status" -> "HTTP Error " <> dlResult["StatusCode"]]];
    ];

    (* convert PDF to html *)
    pdfQ = AnyTrue[{"application/acrobat", "application/pdf", "application/vnd.pdf", "application/x-pdf", "text/pdf", "text/x-pdf"}, 
            StringContainsQ[dlResult["ContentType"], Verbatim[#], IgnoreCase -> True]& ];
    s = If[pdfQ,
        RenameFile[fn, fn <> ".pdf"];
        fn = fn <> ".pdf";
        evData = EvaluationData[StringJoin@ReadList["!" <> pdftohtml <> " -stdout " <> fn, Character]];
        If[Not[evData["Success"]], Return[Prepend[result, "Status" -> "pdftohtml Error"]]];
        evData["Result"]
    , (* else *)
        ReadString[fn]
    ];
    Quiet[DeleteFile[fn]];

    (* read requested elements *)
    elems = Intersection[elements, ImportString[s, "Elements"]];
    i = 1;
    While[i <= Length[elems],
        evData = EvaluationData[ImportString[s, elems[[i]]]];
        If[Not[evData["Success"]], Return[Prepend[result, "Status" -> "Import Error " <> StringRiffle[ToString /@ evData["Messages"], ", "]]]];
        result[elems[[i]]] = evData["Result"];
        i++
    ];
    Return[Prepend[result, "Status" -> "Success"]];
];
ans = importPatched[links, {"Title", "Hyperlinks"}]
```

It produces more or less reasonable results on all links above. It relies on the great [pdftohtml](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/%20pdftohtml) tool. The function basically downloads the link, looks if it is a pdf (in which case the file is transformed to html), and then calls `Import`.

For calling pdftohtml I asked a [separate question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144068/run-external-program-and-capture-its-output-to-stdout) and got help quickly.

Any hints on bugs or possible improvements on this code very welcome! In particular, it would be interesting to know how to include the pdftohtml.exe in a subdirectory of a Mathematica package.