# Run external program and capture its output to stdout

Tags: external-calls

There is `RunThrough` which captures the output and evaluates it. However, I would like the output as String. Is there a direct way without redirecting to temporary files etc.? Here is the code:

```
pdftohtml = "pdftohtml.exe";
pdf = "test.pdf";
ans = RunThrough[pdftohtml <> " -stdout " <> pdf, ""];
```

This fails with the error message

```
Syntax::sntx: Invalid syntax in or before 
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">".
```

Is there a way to get to the output without evaluating it?

Comment: Does `StringJoin@ReadList["!"<>pdftohtml <> " -stdout " <> pdf, Character]` work?

Comment: Or `RunProcess[pdftohtml <> " -stdout " <> pdf, "StandardOutput"]`?

Comment: Thanks I will try this tomorrow

Comment: `RunProcess` may need the list form (see docs) `RunProcess[{pdftohtml,"-stdout",pdf},"StandardOutput"]`

Comment: @yohbs: the first construct `StringJoin...` works perfectly. Please make that an answer, and I will gladly upvote & accept...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
StringJoin@ReadList["!"<>pdftohtml <> " -stdout " <> pdf, Character]
```

Or

```
RunProcess[{pdftohtml," -stdout ",pdf}, "StandardOutput"]
```

Comment: The second command did not work for me, but the first one is a life saver!